# Server error after 'snap find package'

Tags: snap

There is something wrong with my Kubuntu 16.04 as the following command does not work:

```
$ snap find test
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/find?q=test: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

There is no `/run/snapd.socket` file and I tried to reinstall the snap package.

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

**Edit:**

```
$ sudo systemctl status snapd.s*
Failed to list units: No such method 'ListUnitsFiltered'
Failed to expand names: Invalid request descriptor

$ systemctl status snapd.service snapd.socket
Failed to get properties: No such interface ''


$ ls /lib/systemd/system/snap*; echo; systemctl list-unit-files | grep snap; echo; dpkg -L snapd | grep systemd; echo; pgrep -a snap
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.frameworks-pre.target  /lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.service  /lib/systemd/system/snapd.service
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.frameworks.target      /lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.timer    /lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket

snapd.refresh.service                      static  
snapd.service                              enabled 
snapd.socket                               enabled 
snapd.frameworks-pre.target                static  
snapd.frameworks.target                    static  
snapd.refresh.timer                        enabled 

/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.frameworks.target
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.frameworks-pre.target
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.timer
/lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.service
```

Comment: I have snapd 2.0.5 with `snappy-autopilot.timer` & `snappy-autopilot.service` but you have `snapd.refresh.timer` & `snapd.refresh.service`.  let me upgrade to 2.0.8 as yours to check to verify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41192/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-martin-vseticka).

Comment: I have upgraded to Kubuntu 16.10 and the problem with snappy is gone. My system runs on systemd. However, my third monitor stopped working. There is always a catch. :-)

Comment: This is quite a popular question - if you solved the problem and could update with and answer about how you solved it that would really help me and probably some other visitors too.

Comment: As I said in my last comment, I have upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 and it started working. I have never found the root issue though.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the service is running

```
systemctl status snapd.service
```

If not then run it

```
service snap start
```

You should be fine then
(if the service didn't start try with sudo)

Comment: That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the service is not running but I didn't get why. On ubuntu 16.04 server I had to `apt install snapd`.

```
~# snap --version
snap    2.34.2
snapd   unavailable
series  -

~# systemctl start snapd
Job for snapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status snapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

~$ systemctl status snapd.service
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since sam. 2018-08-04 12:38:48 CEST; 6s ago
  Process: 1315 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1315 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I found in the journal that the problem was related to `squashfs`:

`cannot start snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'`

I'm using a `kimsufi` server by OVH and discovered that the custom OVH kernel doesn't support squashfs. I switched to the official ubuntu kernel and now it works!